# Undefined control sequence (\resetOptions) error

Tags: errors

Would someone kindly help what's causing the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\resetOptions ->\@zero 
                       =0\def \pst@linetype {0}\pstScalePoints (1,1){}{}\pss...
l.1900 \resetOptions

? 
! Emergency stop.
\resetOptions ->\@zero 
                       =0\def \pst@linetype {0}\pstScalePoints (1,1){}{}\pss...
l.1900 \resetOptions
```

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[english, landscape, a4paper]{slides}

    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{pst-eps}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{multido}
    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \usepackage{pst-math}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{TeXtoEPS}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

    \newsavebox{\EpsImgBox}
    \savebox{\EpsImgBox}{%
        \includegraphics[angle=90]{foo.eps}
    }

    \begin{pspicture}(\wd\EpsImgBox,\ht\EpsImgBox)
    {
        \rput[lb](0,0){
            \usebox{\EpsImgBox}
        }        
    }
    \end{pspicture}
\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've compiled with TeX Live 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010 and 2011/pretest and had no errors. Would you please add the list of file that you obtain by adding `\listfiles` at the start of the input?

Comment: @egreg: Nice collection!

Comment: @Andrey: not to mention that I can use universal-darwin and x86_64-darwin binaries both with 2010 and 2011 TeX Live!

Comment: I've added \listfiles to the start of my document. Here is the logfile http://pastebin.com/KceYcEhj . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your PSTricks files are not up to date. You can run the TeXLIve manager when using TeXLive or the MiKTeX manager when running MiKTeX or get all current files from http://texnik.dante.de There you'll find all files or a tarzip which has all files in a TeX Directory Structure saved. You can simply copy all files over your current directory structure, run `texhash` and all should then be fine.

Comment: I've upgraded my MiKTeX installation to version 2.9 but I'm getting the error message, ! Package xkeyval Error: `transpalpha' undefined in families `,pstricks,pst-eps
,pst-node,pst-plot,pst-3d,pstricks-add'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: The problem lies with the transpaplha and fillstyle=transparent options of \psframebox.
\psframebox[transpalpha=0.5,fillstyle=transparent,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none,framesep=0pt]{foo}. Have these options been depreciated? (I created this file a long time ago.) BTW, I'm trying to overlay a graphic with text and other annotations.

Comment: Replaced transparency with opacity and fillstyle=solid

Comment: The option transpalpha is no more valid. Read the PSTricks news in http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/